Template not reacting to AngularFire Signout
Trying to follow a slightly outdated linkedin learning path for working with firebase. I have implemented a register page which navigates the user to a profile page and is meant to drive the navigation bar e.g if not signed in, show login/sign up buttons, if logged in.. show a log out button. When i press my logout button, it calls firebase but my ui doesn't change e.g the logout button persists / isLoggedIn$ always appears as true:
  <div class="navbar-end">
    @if((isLoggedIn$ | async) === false){
    <a
      routerLink="/auth/login"
      class="hidden lg:inline-block lg:mr-3 py-2 px-6 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 text-sm text-gray-900 font-bold rounded-xl transition duration-200"
      href="#"
      >Sign In</a
    ><a
      routerLink="/auth/register"
      class="hidden lg:inline-block lg:mr-3 py-2 px-6 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100 text-sm text-gray-900 font-bold rounded-xl transition duration-200"
      href="#"
      >Sign up</a
    >
    } @else {
    <a
      class="hidden lg:inline-block lg:mr-3 py-2 px-6 bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-600 text-sm text-white font-bold rounded-xl transition duration-200"
      href="#"
      (click)="logout()"
      >Logout</a
    >
    }
    {{ isLoggedIn$ | async }}
  </div>

and the component:
export class NavigationComponent {
  fireService = inject(AngularFireAuth);
  isLoggedIn$ = !!this.fireService.currentUser;

  logout() {
    this.fireService.signOut();
    console.log('Logging out');
  }
}

